# What is the correct way to pass parameters to Lightning JS controller from anchor <a>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-events, parameters

I have anchor tag in the lightning component and trying to get the value on user click the hyperlink.

```
//cmp
<aura:iteration items="{!v.refDataList}" var="refData" indexVar="indx">
<div class="slds-media__body">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread slds-timeline__trigger">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-truncate_container_75 slds-no-space">
        <h3 class="slds-truncate" title="{!refData.rf_Id__c}">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{!c.navigateToRefPage}" data-rId="{!refData.rf_Id__c}">
                {!refData.rf_Id__c}
            </a>
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
</aura:iteration>

//js
navigateToRefPage: function(component,event,helper){
    var refId = event.currentTarget.dataset.rId;
    console.log('refId:',refId); //undefined
    var refId1 = event.target.dataset.rId;
    console.log('refId 1:',refId1);//undefined
    var dataset = event.currentTarget.dataset;
    console.log('dataset:' ,dataset);//not returning any attribute in Target
}
```

I want to get the rId value on click of the hyperlink. appreciate any help on this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data-rId="{!refData.rf_Id__c}"
```

Should be written:

```
data-r-id="{!refData.rf_Id__c}"
```

In JavaScript, this will be transformed by changing characters prefixed with `-` to uppercase:

```
let recordId = event.target.dataset.rId
```

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. Worked like a champ.